# Why is my hard drive already partitioned? ASUS ESSENTIO Windows 8

Tags: windows, windows-8, partitioning, oem

I recently bought the aforementioned PC. I have a C drive and a Data drive. Why is this? 
Also, when I look in disk management, the HDD is partitioned into five partitions: C drive, Data drive, 800mb recovery drive, 260mb EFI system drive and another recovery drive of 18 GB. 
Why does the 18 GB recovery drive need to be so large?

Answer (score 3):

Windows is installed on the C drive, as you know.

The 800 MB partition likely contains basic recovery tools, e.g. Startup Repair, and sometimes the Windows bootloader (though not in your case). This allows you to fix basic issues with your system that prevent you from booting into Windows.

The larger recovery partition contains contains all of the software necessary to restore your PC to the condition it was in *out of the box*. This includes the operating system, drivers, any software that came pre-installed on it (trial or otherwise), etc. This allows you to do perform a full recovery or re-installation of your system back to its factory settings.

The data drive is there either simply for convenience, or for you to store your data on in the event of a recovery.

The [EFI partition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) contains the Windows bootloader, as well as bootloaders for any other operating systems installed, drivers for firmware, and "system utility programs that are intended to be run before an operating system is booted."

Answer (score 1):

I cannot guarantee this, but most likely, you have a Data drive because the System Recovery software on the other two partitions will give you the option to fully restore or partially restore. Both will wipe your computer to the factory settings, but the partially restore will not wipe out the data drive. The recovery most likely has two partitions because one is bootable (think of a bootable ISO) which the computer will mount and boot off of to load the System Recovery software. The larger recovery partition contains the actual files for the operating system when performing the recovery.

The EFI partition contains the boot loader programs for all operating systems installed (in other partitions) on the device, device driver files (used by the firmware at boot time) for other devices, and system utility programs that are intended to be run before an operating system is booted. If you want to read more about EFI Partition, refer to the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition).